# Why does ImmutableList have complexity O(logN) in its add method?

Tags: c#, immutable-collections

I think a new ImmutableList of N+1 items is created. Thus its complexity should be O(N).

Comment: Well, they decided to make it more efficient than a naive implementation. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Your belief that an entire new list with more items is created is incorrect. Remember, being immutable means that you can *safely re-use* portions of an existing structure to construct a new structure. That re-use makes for high efficiency in many scenarios.

Comment: If you want to know more about efficient purely functional data structures, I'd recommend taking a look at Chris Okasaki's book.

Answer (score 8):

The reason why ImmutableList has O(log n) complexity is explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget/):

> Why are the immutable types more prone to O(log n) time where mutable
>   types are O(1)? It’s a consequence of the internal data structures
>   that allow sharing across instances of the collections. For instance a
>   mutable HashSet allocates a single array, and stores elements in
>   that array at the index determined by their hash code. This providers
>   O(1) lookup and storage times. If an ImmutableHashSet used this
>   same kind of data storage, then every mutation would require
>   reallocating and copying the entire array just to change one entry,
>   which would quickly tank performance and GC pressure as the
>   collections grew large. Instead, these immutable collections use
>   **immutable balanced binary trees** to store their data, *allowing very
>   efficient data sharing across mutated instances of the collections*. As
>   a result however, every lookup or change requires a tree traversal
>   that has (at worst) an algorithmic complexity of O(log n).

The [MSDN documentation for ImmutableArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn638264(v=vs.111).aspx) provides some insight and shows the complexity difference between ImmutableArray and ImmutableList:

[image]

Comment: That documentation is on `ImmutableList<T>.Builder.ToImmutable()`, which isn't the method being discussed.

Comment: Removed the invalid link. I'll try to look for another from the MSDN documentation.